# Scan for Kontakt.io iBeacons in background Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon

I'm trying to find how to scan for iBeacons in the background but as far as I understood you can only check when the user enters a region, I tried to enable Background Modes then I NSLog the 2 methods that should work in background:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didEnterRegion:(KTKRegion *)region
    {
        NSLog(@"Enter region %@", region.uuid);
    }

    - (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didExitRegion:(KTKRegion *)region
    {
        NSLog(@"Exit region %@", region.uuid);
    }
```

But the devices doesn't seem to scan while in background, what am I missing?

Comment: The methods in the question are monitoring callbacks.  Try using ranging callbacks and starting ranging.

Comment: can you give an example of the code you'll use please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on the Kontakt IO wrapper SDK.  If you are using the iOS built-in CoreLocation APIs, you use the following callback: `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region { }`

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to achieve with Kontakt.io SDK :)
Just check this link http://docs.kontakt.io/ios-sdk/quickstart/#ios-8-compatibility.
I believe you didn't add this to your plist.
When you have it added then in your app after allowing to access your location by app, methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didEnterRegion:(KTKRegion *)region;
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didExitRegion:(KTKRegion *)region
```

will be called and what is even more cool if you'll receive didEnterRegion then automatically will be called(few times) method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons;
```

Of course how to extend background time etc. is a different topic ;)